# Determine if columns have duplicate values sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out a way to check if their is repeated values in rows that are shared.

Example:

```
HMOID     Name      Addon10        Addon15       Addon20
RFFF      Blah      img path1      img path2     img path1
```

For my example, I would like to check if any of the addons for RFFF have any repeated value. In my example above, 'RFFF' has two images that are the same in Addon10 and Addon20 (The images have a path. so currently, they look like 
http://oc2-reatest.regalmed.local/ocupgrade52/images/NDL_SCAN_SR.PNG).

I would like to be able to do this for multiple rows. I thought the following would give me an idea how to begin:

```
select * from HlthPlan
Group By HMO1A, HMONM
Having COUNT(*) > 1
```

However, it throughs the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'HlthPlan.HMOID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

I am fairly new to SQL and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't include all the columns in the select list. Just use like `SELECT HMO1A, HMONM, COUNT(*) AS DuplicateCount from...` or so.

Comment: We can't see your picture at that URL. Is that internal to your network? What is your table structure. Is there actually 20 fields named "Addon<somenumber>"? Can you share your table structure, sample data, and what your desired results would be?

Comment: The absolute best thing you could do would be to normalize your data structures. You have repeating groups here which violates 1NF and makes queries WAY HARDER than they need to be. If you have good data structures, querying is simple. If you have poor structures, getting the back is very difficult.

Comment: @RobertoFlores You have to put all non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include * for your select query. Only include the columns that you are using in GROUP BY

```
SELECT HMO1A, HMONM, COUNT(*) from HlthPlan
GROUP BY HMO1A, HMONM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This will only help if looking for duplicates in the ID/Name rows, but the issue is where there are multiple, similar columns with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

With only three columns to check, assuming non-null values across a single row:

```
select * from HlthPlan
where Addon10 in (Addon15, Addon20) or Addon15 = Addon20
```

You can also use `cross apply` to pivot the values for grouping:

```
select HMOID, addon
from HlthPlan cross apply (
    select addon
    from (values (Addon01), (Addon02), (Addon03), ... (Addon20)) as pvt(addon)
) a
where addon is not null
group by HMOID, addon
having count(*) > 1;
```

http://rextester.com/QWIW87618

You'll get multiple rows for each `HMOID` where the are different groups of columns having the same value. By the way, reporting on the names of specific columns involved would add another degree of difficulty to the query.

Comment: it is more then 3 rows but I just wanted a general idea to check. Your approach gives me an idea but seems like the tedious the way I am thinking of doing it

Comment: @RobertoFlores Are we talking rows or columns? Yes, this stuff is tedious and a reminder why it's a bad idea to store data this way :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant columns, my apolgoize

Answer (score 0):

One way you can check for this is using `UNPIVOT` to compare your results:

```
create table #hmo (hmoid varchar(6), name varchar(25), Addon10 varchar(25), 
                Addon15 varchar(25), addon20 varchar(25));

insert into #hmo
values ('RFFF', 'Blah','img path1', 'img path2', 'img path1');

select hmoid, name, addval, addcount = count(adds)
FROM #hmo
UNPIVOT
(
    addval FOR adds IN
    (addon10, addon15, addon20)
) as unpvt
group by hmoid, name, addval having count(*) > 1
```

Will give results:

```
hmoid   name    addval  addcount 
RFFF    Blah    img path1   2
```

This way you can check against every row in the table and will see any row that has any two or more columns with the same value.

This does have the potential to get tedious if you have a lot of columns; the easiest way to correct for that is to build your query dynamically using info from `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`.